# Need Help on compare and add unique data from Multi dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to compare Multi dimensional array and add unique data from mysql to cloud DB using API.

Perform the search if it doesn't find a match, then add it. otherwise skip to the next. I tried use the following code but it doesn't add any data.

```
      $records=array(

      'SO Qty' => 'Dup !',
      'WO Qty'          => $row['Reference'],
      'SO Date'          => $row['TransactionDate'],
      'Color'         => $row['DistNumber'], 
      'SO#'         => $row['Reference'], 
      'Promised Date'         => $row['GoodThruDate'], 
      'SalesDescription'         => $row['SalesDescription'], 

      );

  $tv->addRecord($tableId, $records); // call to addRecord() which adds data to cloud DB
```

Table A: record from the table where I would like to add data into

```
Array ( 
      [id] => 3054535376 
      [table_id] => 50240233993 
      [created] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
      [updated] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
      [created_by] => 3045444045538 
      [fields] => Array ( 
                        [Work Order] => 87565 
                        [SalesDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
                        [SO#] => 14061 
                        [SO Date] => 2013-10-16T00:00:00-0600 
                        [Promised Date] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
                        [SO Qty] => 1.0000000000000000000 
                        [WO Qty] => 14061 
                        [Color] => 2 
                        [s] => 2 
                        [SHIP BY] => 2014-10-29 
                        [CALC PROMISED DATE] => 2014-10-30 
                        ) 
   )
```

Table B: record from the table where I would like to get data from

```
 Array ( 
       [0] => CAS001 
       [CustomerId] => CAS001 
       [1] => CASH CUSTOMER 
       [Customer_Bill_Name] => CASH CUSTOMER 
       [2] => Will Call 
       [WhichShipVia] => Will Call 
       [3] => [INV_POSOOrderNumber] => [4] => 2013-07-24 
       [ShipByDate] => 2013-07-24 
       [5] => [GoodThruDate] => [6] => [CustomerSONo] => [7] => 13867 
       [Reference] => 13867 [8] => 2013-07-24 
       [TransactionDate] => 2013-07-24 
       [9] => 1 
       [DistNumber] => 1 
       [10] => 2.0000000000000000000 
       [Quantity] => 2.0000000000000000000 
       [11] => 121130581 
       [ItemId] => 121130581 
       [12] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
       [SalesDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
       [13] => [PartNumber] => [14] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFTTIRE 
       [ItemDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFTTIRE
       )
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Leandro Thanks!. sorry for the confusion, here is my problem every time when i re-run or refresh the PHP page adds new and already existing record. I want to avoid adding duplicate records

Answer (score 1):

`$dont_write` never gets set to 0?

Comment: Also, it might just be because it's missing from this snippet, but `$row` (where you're getting the data for the new record) isn't initialized anywhere here.

Comment: Thanks @AlpineCoder i just edited the code added the while loop and  select statement

Comment: So what was the question then?

Comment: Every time when i refresh the page (Re-run the php script) it add duplicate value. i want creat a script which checks and skip duplicate values if any and add the unique once. Need help on how to avoid adding duplicate value. Thanks!

Comment: You don't show where any of this data is coming from in your snippet, but I'd assume if you're getting duplicate values, then the `$id == $a_data['WO Notes']` condition needs to be fixed.